# Deny foreign domains requests with bind9

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, reverse-dns

I have 2 bind9 servers adjusted as Authoritative-Only DNS Servers.
I've noticed that dnstop shows a lot of requests for foreign `financialresearch.gov` domain (not mine). There are more than 50k requests per minute. I can't understand who and why send me requests and how I can block them?

Bind `named.conf.options` config:

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";

    dnssec-validation auto;

    listen-on-v6 {
        any;
    };

    allow-query {
        any;
    };

    recursion no;

    allow-transfer {
        200.200.200.200;
    };
};
```

```
Query Name                Count      %   cum%
--------------------- --------- ------ ------
financialresearch.gov      3442   99.7   99.7
digitalocean.com              2    0.1   99.9
```

dig results:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> @[my-ns-server] financialresearch.gov
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 1034
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;financialresearch.gov.     IN  A

;; Query time: 67 msec
;; SERVER: [my ns server ip]
;; WHEN: Sun Sep 08 00:50:30 +04 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 50
```

Comment: Aren't you already (based on recursion being turned off)?  Check what response you get if you query your own server for that domain name, I would expect `REFUSED`.

Comment: Can you help me to understand how to check response status, please?

Comment: dig can be a lot of help and its readabilities is easy

Comment: Update question with dig results, thanks. The answer status is `REFUSED`. So I have nothing to worry about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't understand who and why send me requests and how I can block them?

Your logfiles should be able to tell you who sends this request but note that most probably you will see only the IP address of some recursive DNS server, not the original client.

As for why, either someone is just poking randomly your site or has a script gone wild and attempting the same misplaced query in a loop. Or your nameservers are using an IP that was maybe previously used by a nameserver authoritative for this domain and some caches did not update themselves.

Since your nameserver already replies `REFUSED` for them, you have nothing more to do.

Except if you think this traffic starts to harm your server/network for any reason, in which case you may want to:

- try to contact the owner of the IP address(es) querying you for this
- be more aggressive and either filter at the IP level this specific address, or this specific DNS query; this is however in general doing more harm than anything, so rate-limiting at the DNS level may be better, see the RRL feature in bind.

Answer (score 2):

This is an attempted DDOS: that host has a large UDP reply [to a spoofed source IP] to an `ANY` lookup.  You're fine refusing the lookups, but to reduce load on your name server, do this:

```
iptables -m string -I INPUT -p udp --dport 53 --algo bm --icase --string FINANCIALRESEARCH -j DROP
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful.

Comment: This will fail in many many cases: will trigger erronously on "NOTFINANCIALRESEARCH", will not trigger if the DNS packet uses name compression and FINANCIALRESEARCH is split in two places, etc... Level 3/4 filtering for the DNS will not work adequatly in many many cases. Looking at RRL features in nameservers is probably better as a first step.

Comment: As for handling `ANY` requests: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8482